# How to fix "Method 'addPostFrameCallback' cannot be called on 'SchedulerBinding?'" in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, android-studio, get, flutter-getx

I'm facing the following error in my Flutter project while working with Android Studio:

```dart
/C:/src/flutterSDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/
get-4.6.3/lib/get_navigation/src/snackbar/snackbar.dart:452:31
: Error: Method 'addPostFrameCallback' cannot be called on
 'SchedulerBinding?' because it is potentially null.

 - 'SchedulerBinding' is from 
'package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart' 
('/C:/src/flutterSDK/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/scheduler/binding.dart').
Try calling using ?. instead.
    SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Can anyone help me understand the cause of this error and suggest a solution?

Comment: same problem here, I tried also downgrading to 4.6.1 but nothing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This error happens because the package get 4.6.2 or 4.6.3 is for new flutter sdk version 3.0. So you got this error. you have to use get 4.6.1 for fluter SDK version 2.xx

I had the same problem.. on "dart.get" package. Then I did this..

> First go to pubspec.yaml file then edit the get version not more than
> (get: ^4.6.1).. if you are using fluter sdk v2.xx.

if the version won't get lower then try this method

> go to pubspec.lock file. edit the version not more than (4.6.1).. if you are using fluter sdk v2.xx.

you will find in  pubspec.lock file

and last you have to do this

> then "pub get" .. error will be gone.

Comment: My flutter version is 2.10.5, and get : 4.6.1 , but still its not working. I tried invalidate cache and restart, tried flutter clean . Nothing helped.

Comment: > First check in External Libraries that it has a folder get 4.6.x somthing.
delete the GET dependencies from puspech..

> then in terminal : flutter pub cache repair

> delete pubspec.lock file..

> then pub get


then do fresh start on GET package
try 4.6.0 then

Answer (score 3):

This is because of recent flutter updates. All flutter `SDKs >= V2.10.3` have this issue. There's no proper solution for this error yet.

**Temporary Solution:**

You can simply downgrade your flutter SDK to `V2.10.2` or lower to get rid of this issue.

**Note:**

After downgrading, make sure you also change the dart version in pubspec.yaml of your flutter project according to the Flutter SDK.

Answer (score 1):

This error is due to some changes happened in null-safety properties in Flutter 3.0.0. In your case you can try to import:
`get: 4.6.1` instead of `get: ^4.6.3`.
Source: https://github.com/jonataslaw/getx/issues/2356

Answer (score 1):

try this

```dart
flutter doctor --android-licenses
```